# Invoke and control GDB from c++

Tags: c++, gdb

Is there any way to invoke GDB and control, access it from c++ program?

Comment: I'm not sure about C++, but the Python bindings might work well for you: http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Python.html

Comment: @Travis Gockel: Thanks for the link. I'll try to get the information from this to get it work in c++.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. Execute it with redirected input/output and simply control it through the pipes.

**EDIT:**

It depends on where you want to do it. On Windows you can use the following: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682499%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

On *nix, the steps described in [Linux Pipes as Input and Output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1734932/linux-pipes-as-input-and-output/1735118#1735118) SO answer should do it.

Comment: @Ambuja: I have edited the answer with links to explain how you could do it.