# invoking gdb in real time from source code

Tags: c++, linux, gdb

I am new to Linux space. 
My project creates 'so' (akin to our dll's) which is used by an executable.
Currently to debug, I invoke  gdb -tui  Which puts me into the gdb terminal where I put break points and do the r with parameters ... and debug. 
Everything was fine, until now where the entire architecture has been changed.

Now to run our code, we execute a command 
$ java -jar  ... and a lot many parameters.
The jar files etc do not belong to us.

I am yet to find out what executable is called, or the code flow.

Question : 
Is there a way to invoke gdb command from within my source code ?

say

```
MyClass::myFunc()
{
    some calls
    <THE GDB COMMAND>
```

What I am looking at is, once I place my 'so' in the path and execute the said java command, the gdb is invoked the moment it hits my function.

The solution provided here wasn't clear.
[Invoke and control GDB from c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7117122/invoke-and-control-gdb-from-c)

Comment: I'm not sure this will work in your case. But you can use `gdb -p [pid]` to debug existing process.  You can find your pid with `ps` command

Comment: wont work, as its the java command picks up and executes an executable and my so in between

Comment: Have your .so file write its PID somewhere (could be a plain file, a FIFO or a udp port) when it is loaded and then sleep for a few seconds. Have another process wait until the PID is written, then immediately invoke `gdb -p PID` (or `gdbserver` or `gdb -tui` or whatever)

Comment: So you are saying, I write the PID to a file, and when my program executes, I open the file, get the PID and the use gdb with the PID and then set the break point to the desired file ?