# Linux Pipe replace stdio - issues with MPI

Tags: c++, file-io, pipe, mpi

This question is the next step after resolving the issue discussed in:

[Piping for input/output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17508626/piping-for-input-output)

I use pipes to pass a string via stdin to an external program called GULP, and receive the stdout of GULP as input for my program. This works fine on one processor, but on two or more processors there's a problem (let's say it's just 2 cores). The program GULP uses a temporary file and it seems that the two processors launch GULP simultaneously and then GULP tries to perform multiple operations on the same file at the same time (maybe simultaneous writes). GULP reports "error opening file".

I am testing this code on a laptop with multiple cores running Ubuntu, but the code is intended for a distributed-memory HPC (I'm using OpenMPI). Assume for the sake of this discussion that I cannot modify GULP.

I'm hoping that there's some straightforward way to get GULP to create two independent temporary files and continue functioning as normal. Am I asking for too much?

Hopefully this pseudo code will help (assume 2 processors):

```
int main()
{
    MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(…);
    MPI_Comm_size(…);
    int loopmin, loopmax;//distributes the loop among each processor

    for (int i = loopmin; i < loopmax; i++)
    {
        Launch_GULP(…);//launches external program
    }

    return 0;
}

Launch_GULP(…)
{
    int fd_p2c[2], fd_c2p[2];
    pipe(fd_p2c);
    pipe(fd_c2p);
    childpid = fork();

    //the rest follows as in accepted answer in above link
    //so i'll highlight the interesting stuff

    if (childpid < 0)
    {
        perror("bad");
        exit(-1);
    }
    else if (childpid == 0)
    {
        //call dup2, etc
        execl( …call the program… );
    }
    else
    {
        //the interesting stuff
        close(fd_p2c[0]);
        close(fd_c2p[1]);

        write(fd_p2c[1],…);
        close(fd_p2c[1]);

        while(1)
        {
            bytes_read = read(fd_c2p[0],…);//read GULP output

            if (bytes_read <= 0)
                break;

            //pass info to read buffer & append null terminator
        }
        close(fd_c2p[0]);

        if(kill(childpid,SIGTERM) != 0)
        {
            perror("Failed to kill child… tragic");
            exit(1);
        }
        waitpid(childpid, NULL, 0);
    }
    //end piping… GULP has reported an error via stdout
    //that error is stored in the buffer string
    //consequently an error is triggered in my code and the program exits
}
```

Comment: A little extra info: When I try this process using redirection with system commands rather than the piping shown above (i.e. GULP < input.txt > output.txt), the first input file gets read and processed correctly by GULP, but the second process fails and the program exits.

Comment: Please can you elaborate on what GULP is ? If its some proprietary software then you probably wont get any help here - as nobody knows how it works. As a last ditch effort you can look at using LD_PRELOAD to hack its open system call to use a path which you can also specify with another environment variable.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Iwan. GULP is an open-source program written for studying molecular structures. It can be found at [link](http://projects.ivec.org/gulp/). I would really like to avoid making modifications to its code because I want my code to simply wrap around it. Once my code is done I'm going to hand it over to someone else to use, and I want to make it as hassle-free for them as possible. I'm looking into the LD_PRELOAD suggestion. Is it easy to implement with pipes? What are the drawbacks/risks?

Comment: I'm also open to suggestions on how to do this without pipes. If piping complicates the issue, I can go back to using: 

GULP < input.txt > output.txt

It will slow down my code but I think parallelization will compensate for that in the long run. Is there a bash command that instructs GULP to put it's temp file in another directory rather than the one containing my program?

Comment: Are you using MPI simply to launch multiple copies of GULP? If so, Open MPI provides a much simpler alternative and also most HPC clusters run under the control of some kind of batch queueing system and most of them support array jobs.

Comment: Hi Hristo. Yes, my code launches multiple copies of GULP. Can you provide an example of what you mean by "Open MPI provides a much simpler alternative"? Right now, I use OpenMPI to split a for loop among processors. GULP is launched during each iteration of the loop via a function call as shown above.