# If I fork() and then do an execv(), who owns the console?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, fork, execv

I am writing a Linux application. What happens if I call `fork()` and then run an application that takes console input? Consider the code below:

```
int process_id = fork();

if (process_id != 0) {
    /* this is the parent process */
    error = execv("../my_other_app", "parameter1", NULL);
    if (error < 0) {
        printf("error!");
    }
} else {
    /* this is the child process. Wait for my_other_app to set up */
    sleep(3);
    /* now continue */
}

printf("########## press ENTER to stop ##########\n");
getchar();

exit(0);
```

The thing is, `my_other_app` also has a **press ENTER to stop** message. So when I do the `getchar()` call, which application is reading it? The main application or the `my_other_app` that I launched with `execv`?

**EDIT:** It appears through testing that `my_other_app` takes priority over the console. Does this happen every time? Is there a way to make sure the console is instead owned by the main process?

Answer (score 4):

Both processes have their `stdin` connected to the terminal (or whatever the original process's `stdin` was connected to). This doesn't change when you call `execv`. If both processes try to read from `stdin` at the same time, it's unpredictable which one will get the input.

If you want to disconnect the child process from the terminal, you should call `setsid()` before calling `execv` to put it in its own session and remove its controlling terminal.

Comment: Note that the sort of disconnect you're talking about does not stop the child from reading from the console; you'd have to reconnect standard input to somewhere else to prevent that happening.  It does stop the child from being sent a SIGHUP when the controlling process exits.

Comment: It's not this simple. Lookup "job control" for details.

Comment: And then do I stop `my_other_app` using the process ID that I captured when I did the `fork()` and send a kill signal to it when I'm ready to stop it?

Comment: Yes, you can do that.

Comment: `setsid()` in the child process does not seem to be working. Pressing `ENTER` still quits `my_other_app`

Answer (score 2):

`fork()` calls `dup()` on every single file descriptor. In effect you get a copy of all the files in the child. Some "processes" (via hooks) may detect the `fork()` and close some file descriptors, but that's very unlikely. Some files may be opened with a specific flag saying that it should be closed on `execv()`. **stdin** is not one of them.

You have two solutions, just close **stdin** in the child process, but that can cause problems, or replace it with `/dev/null`.

```
freopen("/dev/null", "r", stdin);
```

You can do the same for **stdout** and **stderr**.

---

Adding a 'wait forever' at the end of the program (since you cannot do getchar() anymore):

```
for(;;) sleep(0x7FFFFFFF); // for(;;) is probably superfluous
```

That's probably the simplest way, there are many others such as using select() on a file you know will never change...

Comment: Would closing stdout on the child process stop it from dumping output to the console? that would actually be fantastic.

Comment: Do a `freopen("/dev/null", "w", stdout)` for stdout. Then no more dumping. The problem with just closing is that if you have a `printf("something\n");` then it is not unlikely going to crash because FILE * is now invalid.

Comment: Looks like `freopen("/dev/null", "r", stdin);` does not quite work for me, because when reading from `/dev/null` it signals EOF immediately. My program has a `getchar()` call that will terminate it, and it seems that is executed immediately. How can I have it ignore keyboard input and let me kill it by PID manually?

Comment: I made an update to my answer. A simple sleep() of a number so large that you'd anyway have to reboot your computer or it will die of old age before the process wakes up again.

Comment: Ah, bummer. I cannot modify the behavior of this program. The `getchar()` is expected in other uses to terminate it.

Comment: Oh! I see... In that case you could open stdin using a pipe to which you write nothing. That's a bit more work. `man 2 pipe` should get you the necessary info though.

Comment: This question has an answer explaining how to do that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17508626/piping-for-input-output

Answer (score 1):

I think it APPEARS as though `my_other_app` has priority since the other child process has `sleep(3)`.