# Redirect stdin to provide no input at all?

Tags: linux, stdin, kill, getchar, freopen

In [another question I asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21493622/if-i-fork-and-then-do-an-execv-who-owns-the-console/21493903) I realized I want to redirect `stdin` but have it provide absolutely no input. For example, I want a call to `getchar()` to hang forever. I would then like to terminate the application by sending a kill signal.

I tried `freopen("/dev/null", "r", stdin);` but this does not work because `/dev/null` when read returns an `EOF` which it seems triggers the `getchar()` to be executed, and my program is exited.

How can I redirect `stdin` to not read from anything at all?

Comment: End of file is a pseudocharacter in the Linux/C world, typically with the value -1. If you want to wait until killed, reading from stdin is not the way to do it. Edit your question, or submit another.

Answer (score 2):

On linux, you could try to create a named pipe: http://linux.die.net/man/3/mkfifo and just read from it.

But what are you trying to ultimately achieve? It seems there must be a better way.

Comment: I like this approach. I tried `mkfifo("empty_input", S_IRUSR| S_IWUSR);` and then `freopen("./empty_input", "w", stdin);`. I am assuming this would work, but my `mkfifo` call returns `-1` and sets `errono` to `EACCES` which is "permission denied"

Comment: I tried it and for me it executes without error and it just hangs on `open("./empty_input", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666` (output of strace).

Comment: I tried running `mkfifo empty_input` from the command line and seems that the command is not found on my OS. This is an embedded Linux kernel.

Comment: Yea, it seems that mkfifo is not implemented in some OSs (MacOS, ...). Which embedded system do you have? I am not sure if it changes anything but you can try using mknod instead: `mknod("empty_input", S_IFIFO|0600, 0);` http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mknod.2.html That the `mkfifo` _command_ is not present doesn't necessarily mean anything, IMO.

Comment: I am so close - I have this working. But `getchar()` seems to return if I write nothing (because of EOF) or a character if I do write something but do not put a newline char (`\n`). What should I write to the FIFO that a call to `getchar()` will hang on?

Comment: No problem, what's the workaround then? :) Btw, for me it hanged when I just tried to open the FIFO, I didn't have to do anything else.

Comment: I edited the other application to see if when it reads from `stdin` if its equal to a special character. If it is, then I `sleep()` in that app.