# Entering command as a parameter to another application

Tags: c++, linux

I am using [Virtuoso engine](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/). For entering a query into Virtuoso engine, the following needs to be done:

The virtuoso engine starts and gives the command prompt:

```
[myMachine]$ ./isql 1111 
Connected to OpenLink Virtuoso
Driver: 07.20.3213 OpenLink Virtuoso ODBC Driver
OpenLink Interactive SQL (Virtuoso), version 0.9849b.
Type HELP; for help and EXIT; to exit.
SQL>
```

The query `"sparql select ?a?b?c where{graph ?g{?a ?b ?c} };"` is entered by the user as following:

```
[myMachine]$ ./isql 1111 
Connected to OpenLink Virtuoso
Driver: 07.20.3213 OpenLink Virtuoso ODBC Driver
OpenLink Interactive SQL (Virtuoso), version 0.9849b.
Type HELP; for help and EXIT; to exit.
SQL> sparql select ?a?b?c where{graph ?g{?a ?b ?c} };
```

Now in order to automate the process of inserting queries into Virtuoso I wrote the user entered value:`"sparql select ?a?b?c where{graph ?g{?a ?b ?c} };"` into a text file (`mytext.txt`) and used the following command:

```
[myMachine]$ ./isql 1111 < mytext.txt
```

However still the Virtuoso prompt appears as the following -- asking me to enter the query string:

```
[myMachine]$ ./isql 1111 < mytext.txt
Connected to OpenLink Virtuoso
Driver: 07.20.3213 OpenLink Virtuoso ODBC Driver
OpenLink Interactive SQL (Virtuoso), version 0.9849b.
Type HELP; for help and EXIT; to exit.
SQL>
```

Is there some way in linux or c++: by which using shell script (for linux) or system calls for c++ I can enter my query string into Virtuoso. I need to run 10,000 queries therefore manually entering 10,000 queries in Virtuoso is a pain.

([Question also asked on Virtuoso support forum](http://boards.openlinksw.com/support/viewtopic.php?f=12&t=6047).)

Comment: C or C++? Which one is it?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Any will work.

Comment: @St​​​​​​​​​​​​eg: But which one are you actually using?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit C++-11

Comment: I don't know enough about Virtuoso to answer this but I agree it's strange and frustrating that it would not accept piped input to the parent process.

Comment: This looks like a case of reading the tool’s documentation, not solving it with programming. There’s probably a command line argument to pass the input via standard input.

Comment: What about using a controlled [`pipe()`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17508626/piping-for-input-output)?

Comment: Actually, try passing `-b` to `isql` to enable batch mode. [docs](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/isql.1.html) Looks like this is a question about using some third-party program? Originally it looked like this was a third-party library inside your own code (`isql` being your own executable) because, well, I made the mistake of assuming that a question on a programming site was about programming!

Comment: @KonradRudolph I searched through tool's documentation but could not find any. Therefore, as a work around I thought of passing as command line argument

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Thanks a lot...Can you please explain that with an example

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Thanks a lot...Can you please explain that with an example

Comment: @StegVerner: No, I cannot. Just try it. We cannot try it for you.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Ok...I understand. so do you  mean I should try something like: [myMachine]$ ./isql 1111 -b < mytext.txt

Comment: @StegVerner: Something like that yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways you might script interactions with [Virtuoso](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/) (produced by my employer, [OpenLink Software](http://www.openlinksw.com/)), both involving [iSQL](http://docs.openlinksw.com/virtuoso/isql.html) and not.

Depending on the specific queries you're running, and what you plan to do with the results, some approaches might be better than others -- such as using `curl` with SPARQL query request URIs that include data serialization instructions (e.g., CSV, Turtle, TriG) for the resulting output file.  There's not enough information here to know which direction to pursue.

StackOverflow is not usually the best place for product-specific, non-programming questions.  Virtuoso-specific questions are usually best raised to the [Virtuoso Users mailing list](http://sourceforge.net/p/virtuoso/mailman/virtuoso-users/), the [public OpenLink Software Support forums](http://boards.openlinksw.com/support/index.php), or [a confidential Support Case](http://support.openlinksw.com/support/online-support.vsp).

Answer (score 1):

[The manpage for `isql`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/isql.1.html) is quite clear:

> isql  can  be  used to submit SQL to a data source and to format/output results.  **It can be used in batch or interactive mode.**

And:

> **-b**      Batch mode.  It will not do any prompting.

Which is exactly what you want, no?

```
[myMachine]$ ./isql 1111 -b < mytext.txt
```

Slightly confusing is that there is an example of piping data to `isql` even without `-b`:

> **cat My.sql | isql WebDB MyID MyPWD -w**
>   Each line in My.sql must contain exactly 1  SQL  command  except for the last line which must be blank.

---

<sub>***Disclaimer:*** I have no idea what OpenLink Virtuoso is or does; I'm just performing reading comprehension for you.</sub>

Comment: Thanks a lot :). It is giving me: Enter password for -b : When I enter "[myMachine]$ ./isql 1111 -b < mytext.txt"

Comment: @StegVerner: Then enter your password.

Comment: I entered but does not work...The logs say: Error calling DB.DBA.DBEV_LOGIN [42000] : U0002: The object "-b" does not exist.

Comment: Look @Steg you're going to have to try some things, experiment and do some research. I can't do every little step for you.

Comment: You are right... :) But I am a little bad with linux...my bad

Comment: You have to put `-b` before `1111`

Comment: Note -- The `isql` that ships with unixODBC (which was the source of the manpage quoted above) is not the same as the `isql` that ships with Virtuoso. The manpages are not interchangeable. (My employer is [OpenLink Software](http://www.openlinksw.com/); we produce [Virtuoso](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/).)

Comment: @TallTed: That's good intel. Can you link to documentation for the Virtuoso `isql`?