# Passing Arguments Through system() in C++

Tags: c++, bash, shell, variables

How would I pass a command line variable though a system() command in c++.
I have tried using:

```
string i;
i = system("./findName.sh");
i += argv[1];
cout << i;
```

But when  i run this it gives me my condition for wrong number of arguments i have written in my shell script.

This is the output I received when running my program with "./findName brandonw". Which is my executable file ran with the argument i want my shell script to run with.

```
The arguments you put are:
brandonw
usage: findName.sh [only_one_argument]
```

Comment: For a start, you're trying to append it to the output, not the input. And `system` does not return a `std::string`. You need to get into the habit of consulting some _documentation_.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/system

Answer (score 1):

Just concatenate it to the command string.

```
string command = "./findName.sh";
command = command + " "  + argv[1];
system(command.c_str());
```

Answer (score 0):

Just rearrange your code a bit:

```
string i("./findName.sh ");
i += argv[1];
system(i.c_str());
cout << i;
```

---

Also note, that [system](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/system) doesn't return a `std::string`, but an implementation defined `int` value.

If you need to deal with `./findName.sh`'s output, you rather need [`pipe()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17508626/piping-for-input-output).