# why can't I pipe output from both execl calls?

Tags: c++, pipe, dup2

Possible duplicates:

- [How to call execl() in C with the proper arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12596839/how-to-call-execl-in-c-with-the-proper-arguments)
- [Grabbing output from exec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7292642/grabbing-output-from-exec)
- [Linux Pipes as Input and Output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1734932/linux-pipes-as-input-and-output)
- [Using dup2 for piping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642732/using-dup2-for-piping)
- [Piping for input/output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17508626/piping-for-input-output)

I've been trying to learn piping in Linux using dup/dup2 and fork the last 3 days. I think I got the hang of it, but when I call two different programs from the child process, it seems that I am only capturing output from the first one called. ***I don't understand why that is and/or what I'm doing wrong. This is my primary question.***

Edit: I think a possible solution is to fork another child and set up pipes with dup2, but I'm more just wondering why the code below doesn't work. What I mean is, I would expect to capture stderr from the first execl call and stdout from the second. This doesn't seem to be happening.

My second question is if I am opening and closing the pipes correctly. If not, I would like to know what I need to add/remove/change.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

#define READ_END 0
#define WRITE_END 1

void parentProc(int* stdoutpipe, int* stderrpipe);
void childProc(int* stdoutpipe, int* stderrpipe);

int main(){
    pid_t pid;
    int status;

    int stdoutpipe[2]; // pipe
    int stderrpipe[2]; // pipe

    // create a pipe
    if (pipe(stdoutpipe) || pipe(stderrpipe)){
        std::cerr << "Pipe failed." << std::endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    // fork a child
    pid = fork();
    if (pid < 0) {
        std::cerr << "Fork failed." << std::endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    } 
    // child process
    else if (pid == 0){
        childProc(stdoutpipe, stderrpipe);  

    }
    // parent process
    else {
        std::cout<< "waitpid: " << waitpid(pid, &status, 0)
             <<'\n'<<std::endl;
        parentProc(stdoutpipe, stderrpipe);
    }

    return 0;
}



void childProc(int* stdoutpipe, int* stderrpipe){
    dup2(stdoutpipe[WRITE_END], STDOUT_FILENO);
    close(stdoutpipe[READ_END]);

    dup2(stderrpipe[WRITE_END], STDERR_FILENO);
    close(stderrpipe[READ_END]);

    execl("/bin/bash", "/bin/bash", "foo", NULL);
    execl("/bin/ls", "ls", "-1", (char *)0);

    //  execl("/home/me/outerr", "outerr", "-1", (char *)0);

    //char * msg = "Hello from stdout";
    //std::cout << msg;

    //msg = "Hello from stderr!";
    //std::cerr << msg << std::endl;

    // close write end now?
}

void parentProc(int* stdoutpipe, int* stderrpipe){
    close(stdoutpipe[WRITE_END]);
    close(stderrpipe[WRITE_END]);

    char buffer[256];
    char buffer2[256];
    read(stdoutpipe[READ_END], buffer, sizeof(buffer));
    std::cout << "stdout: " << buffer << std::endl;

    read(stderrpipe[READ_END], buffer2, sizeof(buffer));
    std::cout << "stderr: " << buffer2 << std::endl;

    // close read end now?
}
```

When I run this, I get the following output:

```
yfp> g++ selectTest3.cpp; ./a.out 
waitpid: 21423

stdout: hB�(6
stderr: foo: line 1: -bash:: command not found
```

The source code for the "outerr" binary (commented out above) is simply:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    std::cout << "Hello from stdout" << std::endl;
    std::cerr << "Hello from stderr!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

When I call "outerr," instead of ls or "foo" I get the following output, which I would expect:

```
yfp> g++ selectTest3.cpp; ./a.out 
waitpid: 21439

stdout: Hello from stdout

stderr: Hello from stderr!
```

Comment: The children should close the write ends of the pipes after the `dup2()` calls.  If you connect a pipe to a standard I/O channel with `dup2()`, you should almost always close both ends of the pipe.  You may get away without it, but tidiness dictates that you don't try to do so.  The parent process correctly closes the write ends of the pipes; arguably, it should close the read ends once it has done, but if you're about to exit, it won't matter very much.

Comment: +1, I wasn't convinced I was closing everything correctly, so thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Hey Jonathan, if you're still around/willing to answer a question, I was wondering if I should close stdout, stderr at the end of the parent and child? Thanks again

Comment: If your program is about to exit normally, you don't need to close stdout or stderr at the end of your program; the system will close them anyway.  If you're about to abnormally exit (using `_exit()` or `_Exit()` or something like that), then you should consider flushing or closing the standard I/O streams.  The canonical 'Hello World' program in C does not explicitly close stdout or stderr; it is perfectly correct not to do so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**On `execl`**

Once you successfully call `execl` or any other function from the `exec` family, the original process is completely overwritten by the new process. This implies that the new process never "returns" to the old one. If you have two `execl` calls in a row, the only way the second one can be executed is if the first one fails.

In order to run two different commands in a row, you have to `fork` one child to run the first command, `wait`, `fork` a second child to run the second command, then (optionally) `wait` for the second child too.

**On `read`**

The `read` system call does not append a terminating null, so in general you need to look at the return value, which tells you the number of bytes actually read. Then set the following character to null to get a C string, or use the range constructor for `std::string`.

**On pipes**

Right now you are using `waitpid` to wait until the child process has already finished, *then* reading from the pipes. The problem with this is that if the child process produces a lot of output, then it will *block* because the pipe gets full and the parent process is not reading from it. The result will be a deadlock, as the child waits for the parent to read, and the parent waits for the child to terminate.

What you should do is use `select` to wait for input to arrive on either the child's `stdout` or the child's `stderr`. When input arrives, read it; this will allow the child to continue. When the child process dies, you'll know because you'll get end of file on both. *Then* you can safely call `wait` or `waitpid`.

Comment: Excellent.  +2 (or 3) if I could, but I can't. Note that `/bin/bash` probably launches successfully as far as `execl()` is concerned even if it cannot find `foo` to execute.  It is the running shell that diagnoses the problem, not a failure to execute `/bin/bash`.

Comment: Thanks! This really helps. I was actually waiting to get this part down before I started playing with select, so it sounds like I'm going in the right direction. The bit about execl definitely explains a lot to me, so thanks again for the great explanation.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler That's a good point. As soon as the kernel has decided to allow your process to execute the program given in the first argument to `execl`, the call is "successful". In fact, I recently discovered that, on Linux, it's successful even if the new program's bss exceeds resource limits. In that case the new process gets SIGKILL before it even executes a single instruction, but the old process is gone too.

Answer (score 3):

The `exec` family of functions replace the current process image with a new process image. When you execute,

```
execl("/bin/bash", "/bin/bash", "foo", NULL);
```

the code from the current process is not executed any more. That's why you never see the result of executing

```
execl("/bin/ls", "ls", "-1", (char *)0);
```

Comment: +1.  Note that `/bin/bash` probably launches successfully as far as `execl()` is concerned even if it cannot find `foo` to execute.  It is the running shell that diagnoses the problem, not a failure to execute `/bin/bash`.

Comment: Thanks, another great answer. This is really helping me understand what is going on.